# curl output file replacing path seperator with underscore when writing the file

Tags: batch-file, curl, ftp

I'm trying to create a fairly simple batch file to download a file from our ftp site and store it in a specific directory. I would like to be able to put the batch file in the path so I can call it from anywhere. Currently I have a line like the following:

```
curl -v -u %FTP_USER%:%FTP_PASS% -Q "TYPE I" -o %OUTPUT_PATH% "ftp://%FTP_HOST%/%JAR_FILE_NAME%"
```

What I've discovered is that no matter the value of the output path, the file is always written in the current directory, and any path seperators are converted to underscores in the file name. This happens no matter if I use a '\' or '/' and if I try to escape it with double slashes I just end up with two underscores. Quotes around things don't seem to help either.

My question is does the -o option allow for outputting to a folder other than current working dir? I guess I can have the next step in the script to be "move the file to its destination", but that seems really kludgey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exactly like a regression ([reported here](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2016-01/0014.html)) we unfortunately brought in curl 7.47.0. We hope to release an updated, fixed, version soon and in the mean time you can probably consider downgrading to an earlier version to work-around this annoying issue.

Comment: ok that looks exactly like the problem. Fortunately in this case its on a jenkins slave that will not be used for anything else, so downgrading won't be an issue.